# MVVM - get selected items from ListBox via Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am writing app using MVVM pattern in C#.

My goal is to get selected items from ListBox in my own User Control.

I have created bindable object, with method to change this object (called when something new is selected):

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    ...

    public IEnumerable SelectedItems
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IEnumerable),
            typeof(MyUserControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable),
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public MyUserControl ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedItems = ListBox.SelectedItems;
    }
}
```

There is also Items part, and in xaml part ListBox is named ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox" SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged" ... />
```

This how it looks in page with ViewModel, in which MyUserControl is created:

```
<uc:MyUserControl ... SelectedItems="{Binding Path=MyObjectItems}" />
```

And here comes the problem. When setting SelectedItems in ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<MyObject> _myObjectItems;

public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjectItems
{
    get { return _myObjectItems; }
    set { _myObjectItems = value; }
}
```

No matter what I do, `value` will always be null. This also means, that `SelectedItems` in `MyUserControl` is null, too.

I can, for example use `OneWayToSource` binding mode:

```
<uc:MyUserControl ... SelectedItems="{Binding Path=MyObjectItems, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

`value` is still null, same as `MyObjectItems`, but at least `SelectedItems` in `MyUserControl` contains selected items. Not good enough :/

Comment: What is `typeof(ListBoxWithMultipleSelection)`? And when is `SelectionChanged` supposed to be called? Please try to provide all relevant details.

Comment: Why dio you have `SelectedItems`both (as dependency property) in the control and in the view model?

Comment: Just a note, for true MVVM you need to use a view model instead of the control code behind. Thus allows you to separate the logic from you UI and also makes unit testing business logic much easier.

Comment: @RobHusband yeah, thats why using `CheckListBox` is great solution. While using `ListBox` I could not figure way to bind list of selected items. But now I can bind list to `SelectedItemsOverride` property and do everything I need in ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying different approaches I've found NuGet package [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit). List `SelectedItemsOverride` from class `CheckListBox` allows to bind list of selected items:

```
<UserControl x:Class="View.UserControls.MyUserControl"
             ...
             xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
             x:Name="Root">
   <Grid>
      <xctk:CheckListBox Name="ListBox"
          ItemSelectionChanged="SelectionChanged"
          SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=Root}"
          ... />
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And because of that, binding:

```
<uc:MyUserControl ... SelectedItems="{Binding Path=MyObjectItems}" />
```

works! I have access to selected items in View Model - everything in simple way.